# Disable and enable Jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, events, autocomplete

The Jquery autocomplete ([LINK)](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) has an option to turn it off, which looks like this:

```
$(input).autocomplete({ disabled: true });
```

I would like it to be turned off because its default settings is to respond on keyup. I much rather have it function on keydown. So I turned it off and I wrote a function with an event keydown like this:

```
timer = 0;
function func (){ 

var val = $(input).val();
$(input).autocomplete('search', val);
}


$(input).live('keydown', function(){

    if (timer) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }

    timer = setTimeout(func, 50000); 
     $(input).autocomplete( "enable" );
});
```

It doesn't work...meaning it does not do search after 50000 ms but instead it does the default setting with keyup. What should I change?

Comment: Why would you rather have it work on `keydown`?

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker because its faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a keyup event and stop the event propogation.

Add a keydown event and call it like this: `$("input").autocomplete('search', 'demo-value');`

```
$(input).autocomplete().keyup(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
}).keydown(function() {
$(this).autocomplete('search', $(input).val());  //this or $(input)...
});
```

Comment: Still have to test it, but it looks good (I think this will work) Thanks(:

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#autocomplete" )
      .keydown( function( event ) {
            var isOpen = $( this ).autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" );
            var keyCode = $.ui.keyCode;
            if ( !isOpen && ( event.keyCode == keyCode.UP || event.keyCode == keyCode.DOWN ) ) {
                  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            }

      })
      .autocomplete({
            source: someSource
      });
```

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean with id autocomplete? Do you mean the input?? What is keyCode.UP/DOWN??

Comment: This example was posted from the jquery forums with regards to a user trying to get the up and down arrows to work.